# calling a function within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

Defining a function and calling "callback"

```
var evenDoubler = function(number, callback) {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
             callback(null, number * 2)
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Directly calling "callback"

```
var evenDoubler = function(number, callback) {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        setTimeout(callback(null, number * 2), 100);
    }
}
```

Whats the difference between these 2 approaches?

Comment: The difference is that the second snippet doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: @Teemu technically is *works* but not the way a Timeout is supposed to run. @OP `setTimeout` expects a function as a parameter. By running `setTimeout(callback(null, number * 2), 100);`, you're saying that the return of `callback` is the parameter. It executes immediately. That's why in the first example, you have an anonymous function as the parameter instead.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yeah, I've tried to clarify the comment.

Comment: Arguments are *eagerly* evaluated (there might be another term for that but I can't remember). That means that `foo(bar())` will **always** call `bar` first and pass the return value to `foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "directly" call `callback()`, that happens **before** the timer goes off; it happens before the call to `setTimeout()` happens.

An expression like

```
callback(null, number * 2)
```

is a function call, and as such it's always evaluated when JavaScript needs its value. When it's used in a function call:

```
setTimeout(callback(null, number * 2), 100);
```

then it's evaluated in order to get the value that needs to be passed to `setTimeout()`. It's the same as if you call some function with a simple arithmetic expression:

```
someFunction(x + y);
```

You fully expect that what's passed to the function is the *sum* of `x` and `y`. A function call is just another sort of expression, and it too will be fully evaluated when it's used as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` takes as first argument a function reference. So when you call a function (as in your second case), that function *call* should return a function. This is not your case. You want to pass the function reference -- so don't call it. You could do it with `bind` which does return a new function, with the arguments already bound to it:

```
var evenDoubler = function(number, callback) {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        setTimeout(callback.bind(null, null, number * 2), 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is already answered but I want to chime in as I have tested this solution when I was going through the same course.

If you really want to do the "dirty" call in a neat way then give the first argument as just the function name, rest of the parameters after timeout period, as explained here:

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

going by above explanation I tested the code with below and worked:

```
var eventDoubler = function (num, callback) {
    var waitTime = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxTime+1));

    if( num % 2 ) {
        setTimeout(callback, waitTime, new Error('Odd Input'));
    } else {
        setTimeout(callback, waitTime, null, num*2 , waitTime );
    }
};
```